# am I doing this integration by parts right

Tags: probability, limits, integration

I am supposed to show that $-\int_{-\infty}^a f(t)dt =\int_{-\infty}^a (t-a)f'(t)dt$ where $f$ is the cdf of a RV. 
Now what I do is $RHS= \int_{-\infty}^a tf'(t)dt-a\int_{-\infty}^a f'(t)dt=\int_{-\infty}^a tf'(t)dt-a f(a)$

Now, $\int t f'(t)dt= t f(t)-\int f(t)dt$ implying $\int_{-\infty}^a tf'(t)dt = tf(t)|_{-\infty}^a - \int_{-\infty}^a f(t)dt$. This means, to show RHS=LHS we need $tf(t)|_{-\infty}^a = a f(a)$.

This would be true only if $\lim_{t\rightarrow-\infty} tf(t)=0$. So I was wondering why this would be true. I know that since $f$ is a cdf, as $t$ goes to $-\infty$ $f(t)$ vanishes, but why would the product $tf(t)$ also vanish? Or am I doing something wrong in this apporach?

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be a random variable with cdf $f$ and let $X_- = \min \{ X, 0 \}$. $- X_-$ is a positive rv so it satisfies 
$$ \mathbb E ( - X_-) = \int_0^\infty \mathbb P(- X_- \geq t) dt \Longleftrightarrow \mathbb E ( X_-) = - \int_{-\infty}^0 \mathbb P( X \leq t) dt. $$
Now two possibilities, either $E ( X_-) = - \infty$ in which case $\int_{-\infty}^a \mathbb P( X_- \leq t) dt = \infty$ for all $a$. The other possibility is that $E ( X_-) > - \infty$ in which case we can prove, using the monotonicity of $f$, that 
$$ \lim_{t \to -\infty} t f(t) = 0.   $$